# Does Asp.Net Core 3.0 cache views/output differently than version 2.2?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, webpack

I started noticing an issue in my development setup earlier today, that I've never seen before.

I have an Asp.Net Core application with a default route serving a javascript bundle built with webpack. This default route uses a view called Index.cshtml.

Index.cshtml is automatically generated by webpack from a different file, using the webpack plugin HtmlWebpackPlugin. Every time webpack rebuilds the bundle, it overwrites Index.cshtml with a new version, containing a script tag that points to the freshly built bundle.

The Asp.Net application runs inside a docker container, but Visual Studio automatically mounts the applications root folder to the corresponding folder on the host, so static files can be updated without needing to rebuild the container.

This setup has worked for over a year until today.

Now, for some reason, when a new bundle is built, the resulting HTML that comes out of Asp.Net still points to the old bundle. At first, I thought there was a problem with the disk mount. However, when I attach to the running container and have a look at Index.cshtml from inside the container, it looks correct (meaning it points to the fresh js bundle).

I upgraded from Asp.Net core 2.2 to 3.0 about a week ago, and I suspect that this is related. I can't find any information on the web that suggests that output caching or view caching works differently by default compared to version 2.2, but I might have missed something.

Anyone has an idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Maybe you use `ResponseCache` and set to `NoStore = true`. Then check again.

Comment: @Also I suspect it is a behavior related to **run-time compilation**. Please add a package reference to  **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation** (`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.0.0" />`), and enable this feature by `services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()`.

Comment: @itminus thanks, that did the trick! I also found this article explaining the details and motivations for this breaking change: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing the same issue:

As @itminus commented, in order to support runtime compilation of razor views, you need to add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` and run

```cs
services
    .AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

in ConfigureServices.